# .io domain DNS and nameserver issue

Tags: dns, ip

I have a domain utopium.io registered with 123reg.co.uk
It is also hosted with 123reg - under a different account, but used to be hosted by Lunarpages.

I have updated the nameservers (weeks ago) to 123reg nameservers (ns.123-reg.co.uk and ns2.123-reg.co.uk as per their instructions) but when I do a whois on the domain (http://www.nic.io/go/whois/utopium.io) it still shows the Lunarpages nameservers and pinging the domain shows it is still pointing to a Lunarpages server (67.210.122.47) even though I have configured the DNS to point to 123reg IP (46.32.240.39).

I've tried contacting 123reg using their live chat but they were useless. Am at a loss of how to get the domain name to point to the correct server. Any ideas?

Thanks.
Clayton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, querying authoritative name servers for `.io` TLD will return four name servers for your domain:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION (1  record)
;; utopium.io.  IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION (4  records)
utopium.io. 86400   IN  NS  ns1.lunariffic.com.
utopium.io. 86400   IN  NS  ns2.lunariffic.com.
utopium.io. 86400   IN  NS  ns.123-reg.co.uk.
utopium.io. 86400   IN  NS  ns2.123-reg.co.uk.
```

which will result in 50% of the queries returning old 67.210.122.47 address.

I as far as I can see, these are your options (some of these you probably already tried):

1. Check with your registrar (123reg) if there is some kind of control panel where you can change authoritative name servers for your domain by yourself (which was quite usual even in 20th century), if not then request them again to delete the old name servers.
2. In the meantime, try to somehow (using an old account there, or by getting in touch with their support) edit the DNS records at Lunarpages, to point to correct IP addresses.
3. Since you are at point 3, you for sure want to change your registrar. This should be possible with no additional cost, except that you will maybe have to purchase one additional year (which you would anyway eventually do).